# deleting records based on aggregate function criteria

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions, sql-delete

I'm using SQLite3 (version 3.8.6) and I have a list of transactions in a database.  I want to `DELETE` the records for ids which have fewer than 10 associated transactions.

I can use this to list the ids and their count values:

```
SELECT id,count(id) AS cnt FROM purchases GROUP BY id HAVING cnt < 10;
```

I tried to use this to `DELETE` records:

```
DELETE 
    FROM purchases 
WHERE 
    id IN 
    (SELECT id,count(id) AS cnt FROM purchases GROUP BY id HAVING cnt < 10);
```

However this gives me an error:

```
Error: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression
```

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: You can't use multiple cols in a subquery here. Remove the Count(id) and then try it. It will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE 
    FROM purchases 
WHERE 
    id IN 
    (SELECT id FROM purchases GROUP BY id HAVING count(*) < 10);
```

Comment: My SQL is very rusty. What records does the `*` in `count(*)` refer to in this case?  I only know of its use in `SELECT count(*)` and there it selects all records.

Comment: It will refer to the complete row, just as it would in a select statement. In this case count(id) would be equivalent as the rows are grouped by id.

Answer (score 1):

What's SQLite supposed to do with this?

```
id in (select id, count(id) from ...)
```

The `IN` operator expects a list, not a rowset.  Omit the named `count(id)` column and use `count(*)` directly in the `having` clause:

```
id in (select id from purchases group by id having count(*) < 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs at your `id IN (SELECT id,count(id) AS cnt FROM purchases GROUP BY id HAVING cnt < 10);`

You used `SELECT id` and `count(id)`, and basically it will returns 2 columns of result. When using `IN` keyword, you are expecting something like: `id IN '001', '002', '003'...`

To solve your problem, you need to rearrange your syntax:

```
DELETE 
FROM purchases 
WHERE 
id IN 
(SELECT id FROM purchases GROUP BY id HAVING count(id) < 10);
```